Construction of the complex numbers without mentioning $i$
I want a construction of the complex numbers that doesn't specify a basis for them in the definition. I consider $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$ to be specifying a basis, because it gives a special status to '$X$'. Similarly I don't allow $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with $(x_1, y_1) \cdot (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2, x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1)$, as $\mathbb{R}^2$ comes with a natural basis, so $(0, 1)$ has a special status.
There are definitions of the complex numbers that avoid bases, like defining it as the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$, but that takes a lot of work to prove existence and uniqueness. You could define it as the unique field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $2$, which is much easier to prove exists and is unique, but this still isn't an explicit construction.
I don't think this is a crazy question because, for example, the $n \times n$ real matrices can be defined as the endomorphism ring of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which arguably avoids specifying any basis for $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed without specifying a basis for it over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Motivation: just curiosity

What about all real valued $2\times 2$ matrices of the form: $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$

@math101 I would consider that to be giving a special status to the basis
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

@Zoe: that's an artifact of the presentation, that set of $2 \times 2$ matrices can be defined invariantly as the set of scalar multiples of rotations. So we only need the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we don't have to make a choice between $i$ and $-i$, which would correspond to choosing an orientation on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Of course $1$ is uniquely specified by being the multiplicative identity so we can't avoid making $1$ special.

We could use Polar terms : $(1,\theta)$ : Multiplication will add up the $\theta$ values. We will end up with $x^4=(1,2\pi)$ , where $i=x$

@QiaochuYuan I hadn't considered that. In that case it's exactly what I was hoping for.

Why was this question closed???

Here is a completely geometric construction of $\mathbb{C}$ from Euclidean geometry, which as desired avoids choosing a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ and in particular avoids making a choice between $i$ and $-i$. According to a remark of David Hestenes somewhere I've forgotten the source of, the basic idea is due to Grassmann, or maybe Clifford. It does not require the concept of a matrix!
We start with the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, equipped with its Euclidean metric; we don't need to choose a basis of it.

Geometric fact: Given any two nonzero $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there is a unique rotation-and-scaling map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (that is, a map which is a composite of a scaling by a non-negative real $r$ and a rotation) such that $f(v) = w$.

This motivates the following: we can define the "formal ratio" of two nonzero vectors $\frac{w}{v}$ to be this unique rotation-and-scaling map. This is like a multiplicative version of defining a vector to be a formal difference of two points. The set of all such formal ratios, wrt a suitable equivalence relation, can then be identified with the set of rotations-and-scalings, which can in turn be identified with the set of complex numbers. Among the rotations-and-scalings there are the rotations $SO(2) \subset M_2(\mathbb{R})$, and among these there are the two rotations by $\frac{\pi}{2}$, namely $i$ and $-i$, but we don't choose between them because we haven't chosen an orientation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. $i$ can be defined as the ratio $\frac{(0, 1)}{(1, 0)}$, and you can show that the complex numbers defined in this way is a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $\{ 1, i \}$.
The meaning of multiplication is clear because it's given by composition of rotation-and-scalings, so the interesting question is how to give an account of addition. If we really want to think of $\frac{w}{v}$ as some kind of fraction then addition should satisfy
$$\frac{w_1 + w_2}{v} = \frac{w_1}{v} + \frac{w_2}{v}$$
and this uniquely specifies addition, because every "fraction" $\frac{w}{v}$ can be rewritten with any particular vector in the "denominator," since we can just apply the corresponding rotation-and-scaling to any particular other vector.
This formal division can be made sense of as a literal division in the Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (here I adopt the convention that the defining relation is $v^2 = \| v \|^2$); in this Clifford algebra it is given by
$$\frac{w}{v} = wv^{-1} = \frac{wv}{\| v \|^2} = \frac{w \cdot v + w \wedge v}{\| v \|^2}$$
so it lies in the even subalgebra of $\text{Cl}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which can be identified with $\mathbb{C}$ (up to the unavoidable $\pm i$ ambiguity). So in geometric algebra the imaginary unit $i$ is actually a bivector, and the same is true of the three imaginary units $i, j, k$ of the quaternions, which are bivectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (not vectors). For more on this see, for example, the first part of Chris Doran's thesis which goes into more detail.
One mild subtlety in this approach is that because the Clifford algebra is noncommutative it does matter a little whether you divide on the left vs. on the right. Switching between these switches $i$ and $-i$.

Similar to @Qiaochu's answer, you can define $\mathbb{C}$ as the subring of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of linear maps $f$ such that there is $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$ $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle = c\langle x,y\rangle$.
There is no basis specified here, only the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The ring structure is just that inherited from $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.
The strange thing about this definition is that mimicking it for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>2$ you do not get a ring, since the set of such linear maps will not be closed under addition. The fact that it works in 2 dimensions is somewhat miraculous from this definition.

When you speak of linear maps maybe it is better to write End(R^2).
